# how to differentiate admin module from main application in bootstrap file in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, module, bootstrapping

Please give me proper solution for my query. I have tried to solve it but not getting any proper solution. Please give me proper solution.

If I remove following line from application.ini file then it is working well for front end application

```
resources.modules[] =
```

After remove it, I am unable to get my created module(Admin) in modules folder with proper layout. I have only one module. In module bootstrap file I have defined  following functions (project/application/modules/admin/Bootstrap.php)

```
<?php
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initAppAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'admin',
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/admin/'
        ));
        return $autoloader;
    }
    protected function _initPlugins()
    {
        $bootstrap = $this->getApplication();
        if ($bootstrap instanceof Zend_Application) {
            $bootstrap = $this;
        }
        $bootstrap->bootstrap('FrontController');
        $front = $bootstrap->getResource('FrontController');

        $plugin = new Admin_Plugin_Layout();
    //    $plugin->setBootstrap($this);
        $front->registerPlugin($plugin);
    }

    protected function _initAuthPlugin()
    {
       $checkAuth = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
       $checkAuth->registerPlugin(new Admin_Plugin_CheckAuth(Zend_Auth::getInstance()));
    }

    protected function _initDoctype()
    {
      global $adminModuleCssPath;
      global $adminModuleJsPath;
      $this->bootstrap( 'view' );
      $view = $this->getResource( 'view' );

      $view->headTitle('Jyotish - Ek Gyan');
      $view->headScript()->appendFile($adminModuleJsPath.'jquery-1.7.2.js');
      $view->headScript()->appendFile($adminModuleJsPath.'jquery-ui.js');     
      $view->headScript()->appendFile($adminModuleJsPath.'tinybox.js');
      $view->headScript()->appendFile($adminModuleJsPath.'common.js');
      $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet($adminModuleCssPath.'jquery-ui.css');
      $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet($adminModuleCssPath.'style.css');
      $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet($adminModuleCssPath.'theme.css');
      $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet($adminModuleCssPath.'tinybox.css');
      $view->doctype( 'XHTML1_STRICT' );
      //$view->navigation = $this->buildMenu();
    }

    protected function _initLayoutPlugin()
    {
         $layout = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
         $layout->registerPlugin(new Admin_Plugin_AdminLayout());

    }

    protected function _initRouter()
    {
        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $router = $frontController->getRouter();
        $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                 ':module/:controller/:action/*',
                 array('module' => 'admin')
              );
        $router->addRoute('default', $route);

        $usersRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
                      ':module/:controller/:action/(?:/page/(\d+)/?)?',
                      array(
                            'module' => 'admin',
                            'controller' => 'users',
                            'action' => 'index',
                            'page' => 1,
                            ),
                      array(
                              'page' => 1,
                            )
                    );

        $router->addRoute('users-index', $usersRoute);

    }

    protected function _initActionHelpers()
    { 
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(APPLICATION_PATH . "/modules/admin/views/helpers");
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPrefix('Admin_View_Helper');
    }

}
```

In modules folder I have created following plugin Layout

```
class Admin_Plugin_Layout extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function routeShutdown(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
       if ('admin' != $request->getModuleName()) {
            // If not in this module, return early
            return;
        }
        // Change layout
        Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout('admin');
    }
}
```

In frontend bootstrap file I have defined following functions(project/application/Bootstrap.php)

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initAppAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'default',
            'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__),
        ));
        return $autoloader;
    }
        protected function _initLayoutHelper()
        {
            $this->bootstrap('frontController');
            $layout = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(
                new Application_View_Helper_LayoutLoader());
        }
    }
```

I have created following helper file in (project/application/view/helper/LayoutLoader.php)

```
<?php
class Application_View_Helper_LayoutLoader extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{

    public function preDispatch()
    {
        $bootstrap = $this->getActionController()
                         ->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
        $config = $bootstrap->getOptions();
        $module = $this->getRequest()->getModuleName();
        if (isset($config[$module]['resources']['layout']['layout'])) {
            $layoutScript =
                 $config[$module]['resources']['layout']['layout'];
            $this->getActionController()
                 ->getHelper('layout')
                 ->setLayout($layoutScript);
        }

    }

}
```

From last two days I am trying to create separate layout for both but I am unable to getting proper solution. When I run admin module in browser, it is working well but when I run frontend application folder it show exception error with layout of admin.

Please provide me proper solution....

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do a layout switching is with a [front-controller plugin](http://devzone.zend.com/1224/front-controller-plugins-in-zend-framework/). You don't need the `LayoutLoader` helper with `preDispatch` hook.

A simple layout-switcher plugin can be implemented as follows.

Place your various layout files in `application/layouts/scripts/`, named the same as your module: `default.phtml`, `admin.phtml`, etc.

In the file `application/plugins/Layout.php`:

```
class Application_Plugin_Layout extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout($request->getModuleName());
    }
}
```

Enable the plugin `application/configs/application.ini` using:

```
resources.frontController.plugins.layout = "Application_Plugin_Layout"
```

or by manually registering the plugin in `Bootstrap`.

Also, make sure your `application.ini` enables modules and identifies your layout location:

```
resources.modules[]=
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be way over thinking this. I'm going to simplify this down to the basic and you can add back as you see fit.

The bootstrap system in ZF1 is a bad joke. Anything that is present in one of the bootstrap files will available to all modules at run and will be run with every request. So keep it simple and keep it light. I normally put all of the _init methods in the main bootstrap and leave the module bootstraps empty.

```
//simplify your bootstrap to minimum
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

    //your app autoloader is the standard autoloader so is not needed here, it better just work.

   /**
    * initialize the session
    */
    protected function _initsession()
    {
        Zend_Session::start();
    }

    /**
     * initialize the registry and assign application.ini to config namespace
     */
    protected function _initRegistry()
    {
        $config = new Zend_Config($this->getOptions());
        Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);
    }

    protected function _initView()
    {
        //Initialize view
        $view = new Zend_View();
        //add custom view helper path
        $view->addHelperPath('/../library/My/View/Helper');
        //set doctype for default layout
        $view->doctype(Zend_Registry::get('config')->resources->view->doctype);
        //set default title
        $view->headTitle('Jyotish - Ek Gyan');

        //set css includes
        $view->headlink()->setStylesheet('/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css');
        //add javascript files
        $view->headScript()->setFile('/bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js');
        $view->headScript()->appendFile('/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js');
        //add it to the view renderer
        $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper(
                'ViewRenderer');
        $viewRenderer->setView($view);
        //Return it, so that it can be stored by the bootstrap
        return $view;
    }


     /**
      * Not sure if this is really required as it seems as though your routes are pretty standard.
      */
     protected function _initRouter()
    {
        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $router = $frontController->getRouter();
        $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                 ':module/:controller/:action/*',
                 array('module' => 'admin')
              );
        $router->addRoute('default', $route);

        $usersRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
                  ':module/:controller/:action/(?:/page/(\d+)/?)?',
                  array(
                        'module' => 'admin',
                        'controller' => 'users',
                        'action' => 'index',
                        'page' => 1,
                        ),
                  array(
                          'page' => 1,
                        )
                );

        $router->addRoute('users-index', $usersRoute);

    }
    protected function _initAuthPlugin()
    {
       $checkAuth = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
       $checkAuth->registerPlugin(new Admin_Plugin_CheckAuth(Zend_Auth::getInstance()));
    }
}
```

The application.ini is a very important part of application configuration:

```
//truncated for example
[production]
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;//PHP
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;//Paths and Namespaces, paths for application resources and library
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "My_"

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;//Front Controller, default settings for controllers and modules
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.frontController.moduleControllerDirectoryName = "controllers"
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = ""
resources.modules = ""
resources.frontController.baseurl = http://example.com
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;//plugins, default paths for resource plugins and action helpers, can also be 
;         //accomplished in the bootstrap
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

pluginPaths.My_Application_Resource = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/My/Resource"
resources.frontController.actionhelperpaths.My_Controller_Action_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/My/Controller/Action/Helper"

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;//View Settings, view settings to be shared with the view object in the bootstrap
;//               allows for easier editing.
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

resources.view[]=
resources.view.charset = "UTF-8"
resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
resources.view.doctype = "HTML5"
resources.view.language = "en"
resources.view.contentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;//Database Settings, default database adapter settings
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

resources.db.adapter = "pdo_Mysql"
resources.db.params.username = "user"
resources.db.params.password = "xxxx"
resources.db.params.dbname = "dbname"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
resources.db.params.profiler = true

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;//Layouts, default path to layout files and default layout name
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.layout.layout = layout
```

Now the simplest way to accomplish layout switching is to switch the layout on a per controller basis, use the default layout except where you explicitly change it:

```
//some controller that needs the admin layout
//note: preDispatch() and routeShutdown() are essentially the same point in the loop
public function preDispatch() {
        //switch to new layout
        $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('admin');

        //you can also manipulate the css and js similarly to the bootstrap
        $this->view->headScript()->appendFile(
        '/javascript/mediaelement/build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js');

        $this->view->inlineScript()->setScript(
            "$('audio').mediaelementplayer();");
    }
```

I find that if I just need one or two different layouts this works nicely and is simple. Not really a ***DRY*** solution but can really help develop the parameters for a plugin if a ***DRY*** solution is desired.

I hope this provides some help, the big thing to remember is that the module bootstraps are basically just extentions of the main bootstrap and provide **no** seperation of functionality.

**P.S.** I would have provided a plugin demo but I really suck at plugins, Sorry.